# Kullback-Leibler Divergence for Graph Sampling

Tags: graphical-model, kullback-leibler

I am from Computer Science background and need to apply Kullback Leibler Divergence to find the divergence between two distributions of unknown types.
Let's say I have a graph G(V,E) and I make a small sample out of it Gs(Vs,Es).
Now I have two degree distributions, the PDF of graph G (lets call it X) and that of Gs (lets call it Y). I apply KLD(X||Y) and get the results and results seems fine. What I want to discuss is that:

1. Since KL is non-symmetric and not a true metric, is it a good test in my case or not? I am confused with the non-symmetric nature of KL and cannot properly grasp the idea if KL test is good in my case or not?
2. what if I calculate the divergence as 0.5*[KLD(X||Y) + KLD(Y||X)]. I read a few papers in my field and both formulas (in 1 & 2) have been used by researchers without any explanation. I would like to know from a Statistician which one is better (if any) and why?

Comment: It seems to me that graph $G$ does not vary (it is given). Then what do you mean by the KL divergence between these two distributions?

Answer (score 3):

The symetric divergence of your formula (2) is called Jensen-Shannon divergence.

I believe you will find the explanation you are looking for on the following [paper](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0049949).
On Results section there is an explanation of Jensen-Shanon divergence for graphs.

There is also a book called "[Mathematical Foundations and Applications of Graph Entropy](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=3i63DAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA183&ots=SyIqGiBxDZ&dq=info%3AhSfJLrD2txAJ%3Ascholar.google.com&lr&pg=PA183#v=onepage&q&f=false)" and a more detailed explanation is available at chapter 6.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @TaianeRamos. Can you post a full citation & a summary of the 
information at the link, in case it goes dead?